# How do you make a light switch that will cut power one with a one minute delay, but give power instantly when turned on?

Tags: switch, timer

I want to install a fan in the bathroom that works in conjunction with the light switch and stays on one minute after being turned off.

How do I pull this off in my bathroom renovation project?

Comment: they make products that do this.  usually associated with motion detectors (the lights are turned off about a minute after no motion is detected and turned on immediately when motion *is* detected).

Comment: A delay off relay could be used but by the time a box is added for the relay it would be cheaper to purchase a digital switch that can do this. Lutron maestro can do this I have used them in the past I think it was 1p seconds fade to off.

Comment: This is a normal feature on many bathroom fans.

Comment: Are you OK with running new wire between the switch and the fan and/or light locations, and where does power come in?